# Making Scientific Calculator in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

[image: This links to an image of my app's form]

---

I want to make program in visual basic that can calculate cosine of any angle in degrees such that when I enter the angle in the textbox labeled "angle text box" and hit the "cos" button it well show the result in "result text box".  This code give the cosine in radians.  I need it in degrees

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = Math.Cos(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The .Net framework's Math namespace trigonometric functions expect to have angles expressed as radians, not degrees.

Before calling `Math.Cos()`, convert your input from degrees to radians, like this:

```
Textbox2.Text = Math.Cos(Textbox1.Text * (Math.PI / 180.0));
```